# Get Map Tiles On the base of Polygon

Tags: javascript, google-maps, cordova, leaflet

I am using `Google Map` in my mobile app ([Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/) App). In which i make some polygon on map as a boundaries. I want that user can view that boundaries/polygon also in offline mode.For offline map i am using [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) but how can i get only specific tiles that are inside that boundaries and save it. (I will do "save it" part by my own i need help on first part how can i get tiles?).

Answer (score 0):

Install the Leaflet plugin called [Leaflet-Boundary-Canvas](https://github.com/aparshin/leaflet-boundary-canvas) & use the function to add tiles to the polygon

```
var boundaryLayer = L.TileLayer.BoundaryCanvas.createFromLayer(tileLayer, options);
```

Where:

- tileLayer - instance of L.TileLayer
- options - L.TileLayer.BoundaryCanvas options (including boundary)

Subsequently you can draw the Polygon using the same plugin using boundary options as LatLng[] - simple polygon.

**EDIT**: See if [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20228241/offer-packages-of-map-tiles-for-offline-use) helps you in specific question regarding offline.

Hope this would Help!!

Comment: does this download tiles? How do i use in offline mode?